# Deserializing an unnamed array

Tags: c#, json.net

I am having difficulty writing the appropriate annotations to represent data which is returned from a JSON Get request which returns data like so:

```json
[
    {
        "ProductCode": "0129923083091",
        "Description": "DIESEL ",
        "SalesLitres": 6058.7347,
        "SalesValue": 6416.2000
    },
    {
        "ProductCode": "0134039344902",
        "Description": "UNLEADED ",
        "SalesLitres": 3489.8111,
        "SalesValue": 3695.7100
    },
    ...
]
```

(ellipsis above just indicating that I could have variable number of these items returned)

In my model class (I am using MVVM approach for a Xamarin project but that's not over relevant here) I am using annotations to represent the  model attributes

```
 namespace App8.Models
    {

        public class ReportRow
        {
            [JsonProperty("ProductCode")]
            public string ProductCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

            [JsonProperty("Description")]
            public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

            [JsonProperty("SalesLitres")]
            public double SalesLitres { get; set; } = 0.0;

            [JsonProperty("SalesValue")]
            public double SalesValue { get; set; } = 0.0;    
        }
    }
```

I would like to annote another class which shows the container/contained relationship. However, I coming unstuck as there is no JSON attribute to provide in the annotation to represent the "root" of the returned collection.

I'd have no problem mapping the JSON to an object model for any JSON arrays which are named within the returned JSON. In that case I could create another class with a named JSON attribute which contained a C# List but I am trying to provide an appropriate model mapping for JSON which returns a list of items within an unnamed array.

Any ideas how I could approach this?

Comment: Congratulations on a well-formulated first question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To deserialize that JSON, use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReportRow>>(json)
```

(or any variant you wish, the key here is asking to deserialize a `ICollection` of `ReportRow`. It could be your own class implementing `ICollection`, or any of the builtins)

The same idea follows to `JsonTextReader` or whatever other means of deserializing JSON.NET offers. Just use a `ICollection<YourType>` as target type.

Comment: Thanks Kroltan. Looks like I am doing it correctly so as that is what I am doing to deserialize it. My problems are further up the stack so within Xamarin forms and how I bind to that list within a viewmodel, etc. That at least helps me in validating that I am using the correct approach to deserializing the JSON.

Comment: @user6911358 Yes, this is usually the correct approach to deserializing root arrays. If you really need your own type (e.g. to implement a custom interface), you can just subclass the `List<T>` type, or some other collection. Even implement your own if really necessary. But it shouldn't, very probably. Post another question with your Xamarin doubts and link it here.

Comment: You deserve 1000 upvotes :)